# Flutter : archive failed in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, plugins, build

I have an app created by flutter want to build it for iOS ,when I want to archive it in XCode it gives me this error :

```
Module Flutter_inappweview not found
```

steps I did and failed to solved it :

I used Runner.xcworkspace in XCode.

I cleaned it in XCode by cmd+Shift+k.

I removed Pod folder and .lock file and rebuild app.

When I remove the line @import flutter_inappwebview ,then it says :

```
Module Flutter_sharedpreference not found
```

### How can I solve it ?

Comment: Yes, Have you recently updated to the latest flutter build?

Comment: @DarshShah must I upgrade flutter to la version?

Comment: Yes, to the latest flutter version.

Comment: @DarshShah it says : already up to date stable chanel

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. clean xcode project or flutter clean
2. open terminal at project dir type 'flutter pub get'
3. cd to ios folder type 'pod install'